# Flutter/Dart Rebuild a Statefulwidget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have the following problem. In a stateful widget (1), which contains a text field, a stateful widget (2) is called, which outputs a text. If an entry was made in the stateful widget (1), the stateful widget (2) should output the current text. (So ​​it has to be updated).

Here is my sample code that unfortunately doesn't work:

```
class _TexfildState extends State<Texfild> {   
String text;   
@override   
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          onChanged: (str){
            setState(() {
              text = str;
            });

          },
        ),
        Textprint(text) //This widget should reload if str changes!
      ],

   );  
 } 
}

 class Textprint extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 final String textprint;
 Textprint(this.textprint);

_TextprintState createState() => _TextprintState();
}

class _TextprintState extends State<Textprint> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(widget.textprint),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try print to console `widget.textprint` value in `_TextprintState`'s `build`. is it called on `TextField`'s value change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to initialize the text with value or so called empty string. Because TextPrint Widget can't receive null String.

```
String text = '';
```